PHP and optional function arguments
By given this function:
function doSomething($var1, $var2, $var3 = true, $var4 = false){
    // function lines here...
}

I want to call the function and pass values to the arguments 1, 2 and 4 bypassing the third argument as it is optional. Is this possible in PHP?
Something like:
$var1 = 2;
$var2 = "some text";
$var4 = true;
$result = doSomething($var1, $var2, $var4);

Or in this case I need to pass a value for the third argument, too?
I try to pass to a PHP function only those optional arguments, where I have a value different than the default one defined in the function itself.

Yes, see named arguments

usage of named arguments for the sample code: doSomething($var1, $var2, var4: $var4);

In php 8.x you can use named arguments
function foo(int $var_a, int $var_b, string $var_c) { ... }

foo(var_a: 10, var_c: 'ola mi amigo');

Reference: https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.named-arguments

Although this is correct, can you post a version that compiles correctly? Maybe give the second and third parameters default values? https://3v4l.org/2gIdE

You can do the following:
1 - Using your logic, you can't bypass the 3rd parameter, but you can just define it when you call the function.
$var1 = 2;
$var2 = "some text";
$var4 = true;
$result = doSomething($var1, $var2, true, $var4);

Other alternative:
function doSomething($values)
{
   $var1 = $values['var1'] ?? null;
   $var2 = $values['var2'] ?? null;
   $var3 = $values['var3'] ?? true;
   $var4 = $values['var4'] ?? false;
   // do something cool
}

$var1 = 2;
$var2 = "some text";
$var4 = true;
$result = doSomething(['var1' => $var1, 'var2' => $var2, 'var4' => $var4]);

Robert C. Martin. states the following

A function shouldn’t have more than 3 arguments. Keep it as low as
possible. When a function seems to need more than two or three
arguments, it is likely that some of those arguments ought to be
wrapped into a class of their own. Reducing the number of arguments by
creating objects out of them may seem like cheating, but it’s not.

I hope I was able to help! Thanks!

"Using your logic, you can't bypass the 3rd parameter" - why not? What about named arguments/parameters?
